# VBA error message "out of range" when referring to worksheet codename

Tags: vba, excel

I want to insert a number, which is entered in a Inputbox, into another table *Tabelle10* but after clicking on the submit button i got the message *"index out of range"* what does this mean?
Is there something wrong with my code?

`If insertNumber>= 0 Then
  Sheets("Tabelle10").Range("F" & lastCell+ 1) = insertNumber
End If`

thx for help.

Comment: the name of the table is _"Maßnahme"_ in excel but at the left side in Vba the name is _Tabelle10_ @A.S.H there are already values I always want to put the value into the next free cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment, `Tabelle10` is the sheet's **CodeName**, not its **Name**. Therefore, you should refer to it by

```
Tabelle10.Range(...)
```

instead of

> ```
> Sheets("Tabelle10").Range(...)
> ```

The "codename" is the name that appears in the VBA editor's project pane, while the "name" is the one that appears in the tab bar of Excel. The codename should be used in VBA like an object variable.

Comment: thx I get no error messages now, but I don't see the value :/

Comment: @flowers1234 that should be due to some other parts of your code. Place a breakpoint on that line and check the values of `insertNumber` and `lastCell`.

Comment: oh my god, it is in line 211????? why it jumped in this line?? I always want the last cell, that means the last empty cell in the column

Comment: @flowers1234 lol, it happens just **a lot**. Hoe did you calculate `lastCell`? the `.end(xlUp)` method is the most reliable.

Comment: xD, but it should be the last empty in the column, this is my code therefore `lastCell= Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row` @A.S.H

Comment: this works only if `Tabelle10` is active at the time the statement executes. Better try to qualify it explicitly: `lastCell= Tabelle10.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row`